# Post date from database

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm new to Laravel 5.1, I don't know what I'm doing wrong when I'm retrieving a date string from the database and trying to show it on blade form.

It doesn't work, the date from de database does not appear on the `Form::date`.

I know I'm missing something crucial here :)

Here is the view code:

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="form-group">
        {!! Form::label('birth_date', trans('userapps/userapps.birth_date'))!!}
        {!! Form::date('birth_date', Input::old('birth_date'), array('class' => 'form-control input-lg'))!!}
        @if ($errors->has('birth_date')) <p class="help-block">{{ $errors->first('birth_date') }}</p> @endif
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the controller code:

```
public function edit($id)
{
    //show all saved values for editing

    $userapp = UserApplication::findOrFail($id);

    $birth_date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $userapp->birth_date)->format('d/m/Y');


    $data = array('birth_date' => $birth_date, 'userapp' => $userapp);

    return view('admin/userapps/edit')->with($data);
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the format that you are storing the date in the database? Is it an SQL `DATE` column?

Comment: String as dd/mm/yyyy

Comment: Please try to add this to your model protected $dates = ['birth_date']; it will format date as Carbon object, see if it helps

Comment: didn't work, but its strange im make converting the string to date again, it should work :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The date input [only accepts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372038/is-there-any-way-to-change-input-type-date-format) values in the following format `yyyy-dd-mm`. Meaning you should format your date value like this:

```
DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $userapp->birth_date)->format('Y-m-d');
```

The browser will make sure to show it according the operating  system locale. For example, if I have a date input with `value="2015-12-05"`, it will be displayed as `05/12/2015` according to my OS locale.

---

Once you have that fixed there is another problem which will most likely prevent the date from being displayed. You're setting the default value to `Input::old('birth_date')`, which is `null` the first time you access the form, because there's no old input data until the form has been submitted. So in your controller action you should do this:

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $userapp = UserApplication::findOrFail($id);

    // Use old input value and if that's not available then use the $userapp one
    $birth_date = Input::old('birth_date') ?: DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $userapp->birth_date)->format('Y-m-d');
    $data =['birth_date' => $birth_date, 'userapp' => $userapp];

    return view('admin/userapps/edit')->with($data);
}
```

And in your Blade view file:

```
{!! Form::date('birth_date', $birth_date, array('class' => 'form-control input-lg'))!!}
```

With this it will use the old input value only if there is one, otherwise it will use the value from the database.

---

That being said, your should be aware that the date input is [supported only by a few browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-datetime). Firefox, Safari and Internet explorer **don't support it at all**, so if you need to make sure the user input is restricted to a date across all browsers, I would use a JavaScript date picker library instead.